# Metrices on countable sets

Tags: real-analysis

Can we define metric (not discrete) on a countable set $X$?

My answer is: we can define a metric $d$ on $X$ by $d(f(n), f(m))=|m-n|$, where $ f$ is a bijection between $X$ and the set of all natural numbers $\Bbb{N}$.

Is my idea correct? Please let me know.

Comment: I'll assume that by "countable" you mean "countably infinite". Unless I'm missing something, just do the same thing with $\mathbb Q$ (or any countably infinite metric space) replacing $\mathbb N.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(Y, d_0)$ is a metric space and $g: X \to Y$ an injective function then
$$
 d(x, y) = d_0(g(x), g(y)) 
$$
is a metric on $X$, as can easily be verified.

That is exactly what you have done, with $g = f^{-1}$ and $Y= \Bbb N$ equipped with the Euclidean distance. Since only an *injection*  from $X$ to $\Bbb N$ is needed for this construction, it works with any finite or countably infinite set $X$.